# SwiftUI: Native menu items navigation to view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have like to use the native navigation menu bar in swiftui but somehow I could not get it to navigate to the settings page.

When I click on Settings menu item, it does show "at setting" but it does not navigate to the view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @StateObject var vm = LoginViewModel()
  @State var selection: Int? = 0
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack {
        if !vm.log_status {
          Home()
            .toolbar{
              ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Menu {
                  Button {
                    print("at home")
                  } label: {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill")
                  }
                  Button {
                    print("at setting")
                    self.selection = 1
                  } label: {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Settings Page"), tag:1,  selection: $selection) { Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill")}
                  }
                } label: {
                  Label(title: { Text("Menu")}, icon: {Image(systemName: "filemenu.and.selection").foregroundColor(Color.black).font(.system(size: 24))})
                }
              }
            }
        } else {
          Login()
        }
      }
      .navigationTitle("App")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to have the `NavigationLink` inside a button itself. You can move it within the `ZStack` and get rid of any label you defined. By doing so, when you tap on the button where "at setting" is printed, you still change the `selection` value which in return triggers the navigation call. I've made a few changes to your code (Read the comments):

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Settings Page"), tag:1,  selection: $selection) {} // Move the NavigationLink to the ZStack and get rid of any labels set.
        if !vm.log_status {
            Text("Home")
                .toolbar{
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Menu {
                            Button {
                                print("at home")
                            } label: {
                                Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill")
                            }
                            Button {
                                print("at setting")
                                self.selection = 1
                            } label: {
                                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill") // Keep ONLY the label of the Previous NavigationLink
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Label(title: { Text("Menu")}, icon: {Image(systemName: "filemenu.and.selection").foregroundColor(Color.black).font(.system(size: 24))})
                        }
                    }
                }
        } else {
            Text("Login")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("App")
}
```

The result:

[image]